# Do we have an alternative for millis() function?

Tags: programming

This is actually a follow up question to [this question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/67125/is-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-makes-arduino-processing-slow), so basically I'm using DS18B20 temperature sensor which requires Onewire.h library that interrupts millis() function.

Luckily i have a [DS3231 RTC](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HCB7VYS) module which I'm using it with [RTClib library](https://github.com/adafruit/RTClib), is there any way to use that module as a timer instead of millis() function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQW output of the module to indicate the passage of precisely 1 second. Every time it transitions from LOW to HIGH one second will have passed.

RTCs cannot give you times of higher resolution than 1 second, but they can give you that 1 second granularity to a high accuracy.

Comment: Thanks, but i don't know how to do that! can you please provide a link to an article/tutorial?

Comment: digitalRead(). When it changes from LOW to HIGH you know a second has gone by.